# What is a CMS that allows inset PHP, stores "templates" on files instead of in a DB, and is easily extensible?

Tags: language-agnostic

Basically I want the flexibilities of ExpressionEngine, and nearly the same idea, yet free. I use EE2 on dozens of my clients sites, but the $299 hit is cutting a ton off my income since most are just easy $1,500 projects.

Most important is the ability to use PHP in the templates/script.

Wordpress looks solid, but I noticed it does not store files on the server, only in a DB. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Wordpress looks solid, but I noticed
>   it does not store files on the server,
>   only in a DB. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I think WordPress has excellent [templating system](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates) and it does not store files in the database but there is a **themes** directory where all files are stored.

To get more idea, have a look at:

- [Visual Anatomy of a WP 1.5 Theme](http://www.transycan.net/abc/visual_anat.html)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent response. So you're essentially saying that I can edit all these things within an FTP and they are files, just the "pages" and "posts" are not?

Comment: @Allen Gingrich: Yes I am talking about template files not the posts which are (and should be) stored in the database of course :)